# How to edit a reactive DataTable?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

So I am currently developing a Shiny App whose goal is to display a table filtered by various parameters (like ID or Year) featuring an `old value` and `new value` columns -identical at first-, whith the `new value` column being editable in order to calculate the difference between the old value and the new value (we'll call it "Main Table").

This app would also need to display the difference between the sum of all the old values and all the new ones to visualize how all the changes impacted the global score (we'll call it "Aggregate Table").

I used the DT package that allows to edit via shiny a DataTable and managed to have the Main Table and the Aggregate Table work using a non-reactive DataTable as input. But when I tried to use a reactive one instead in order to filter it using the needed parameters, it didn't work. I made numerous attempt each with various tweaks to make it work, and the closest that I manage to get to what I want is having a reactive Main Table and Aggregate Table that do change depending on the parameters, but when I try to edit the Main Table the app crashes.

Here is the latest version of the code :

```
###### Attempt at creating an editable reactive DataTable


### Import Libraries

library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


### Quality of Life functions (can be ignored)

f0 <- label_number(accuracy = 1)
f2 <- label_number(accuracy = 0.01)

format_value <- function(f, value, symbol) {
  return(paste0(f(value), symbol))
}

as.percent <- function(x) {
  return(round(100 * x, 2))
}

js <- c(
  "table.on('key', function(e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent){",
  "  var targetName = originalEvent.target.localName;",
  "  if(key == 13 && targetName == 'body'){",
  "    $(cell.node()).trigger('dblclick.dt');",
  "  }",
  "});",
  "table.on('keydown', function(e){",
  "  var keys = [9,13,37,38,39,40];",
  "  if(e.target.localName == 'input' && keys.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){",
  "    $(e.target).trigger('blur');",
  "  }",
  "});",
  "table.on('key-focus', function(e, datatable, cell, originalEvent){",
  "  var targetName = originalEvent.target.localName;",
  "  var type = originalEvent.type;",
  "  if(type == 'keydown' && targetName == 'input'){",
  "    if([9,37,38,39,40].indexOf(originalEvent.keyCode) > -1){",
  "      $(cell.node()).trigger('dblclick.dt');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});"
)


### Data Creation
data_test <- tibble(id = rep(1:2, times = 6), annee = rep(2020:2021, each = 6), 
                    old_value = rep((10:21)*5), new_value = old_value, diff = new_value - old_value)


### Server Section

# Main DataTable function

mod_table_edit <- function(id, data_initialisation) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # initialise the reactive data object for the table
    data <- reactive({data_initialisation()})
    
    # render the table
    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(data(),
                selection = 'none', editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(1:3, 5))),
                callback = JS(js), extensions = "KeyTable", options = list(keys = TRUE)
      )})
    
    # update the underlying data
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
      data() <- editData(data(), input$table_cell_edit) %>%  
        mutate(diff = new_value - old_value)
    })
    
    # return the data as a reactive
    return(reactive(data()))
  })
}

# Second DataTable function

mod_table_add <- function(id, data_aggreg) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # do the calculations
    data_table <- reactive({data_aggreg() %>% 
        summarise(Tot_old_value = sum(old_value) %>% round(), Tot_new_value = sum(new_value) %>% round(),
                  Tot_diff = Tot_new_value-Tot_old_value %>% round(), Hausse_Tot = as.percent((Tot_new_value/Tot_old_value)-1)
        )
    })
    
    # render the table
    output$table <- renderDT({datatable(
      data_table() %>% mutate(Hausse_Tot = format_value(f2, Hausse_Tot, " %")),
      rownames = FALSE, editable = 'none')})
  })
}


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_filt_id <- reactive({data_test %>% filter(id == input$slct_id)})
  
  observeEvent(input$slct_id, {
    choices <- as.integer(unique(data_filt_id()$annee))
    
    # Can also set the label and select items
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "slct_annee")
    updateSelectInput(session,"slct_annee",
                      label = "Annee",
                      choices = choices,
                      selected = tail(choices, 1))
  })
  
  data_filt <- reactive({data_filt_id() %>% filter(annee == input$slct_annee)})
  
  # call the modules for the editable tables and store the results
  data_value <- mod_table_edit("value_table", data_initialisation = data_filt)
  
  # call the module for the table that takes inputs
  # the reactives musn't be evaluated
  mod_table_add("table_aggregats", data_aggreg = data_value)
}



### UI section

# UI module to display the tables
modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("table"))
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "DummyApp"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Tables Calc", tabName = "T_Calc", icon = icon("dashboard")))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "T_Calc",
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 3),
          column(width = 3,
                 selectInput(
                   "slct_id", "ID",
                   choices = unique(data_test$id),
                   selected = 1,
                   selectize = TRUE)),
          column(width = 3,
                 selectInput(
                   "slct_annee", "Annee",
                   choices = unique(data_test$annee),
                   selected = 2020)
          )),
        fluidRow(
          modFunctionUI("value_table"),
          modFunctionUI("table_aggregats")
        ))))
)


### Run Application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am pretty sure that the problem comes from the Server Section and specifically the `# update underlying data` part of the Main Table function, but I can't wrap my head about how to make it work as intended.
I also tried using `reactiValues()` instead of `reactive()`, but without much success either.

Is it possible to have both a reactive *and* editable DataTable with R Shiny ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use make `data` a `reactiveVal` to update it inside the `observeEvent`. To init `data` I use an `observe`. Additionally I added an `req(data_aggreg())` inside the `mod_table_add` to prevent that the table "crashes" before `data` is initialized:

```
# Main DataTable function
mod_table_edit <- function(id, data_initialisation) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # initialise the reactive data object for the table
    data <- reactiveVal()
    
    observe(
      data(
        data_initialisation()
      )
    )

    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(data(),
        selection = "none",
        editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(1:3, 5))),
        callback = JS(js), extensions = "KeyTable", options = list(keys = TRUE)
      )
    })

    # update the underlying data
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
      data(
        editData(data(), input$table_cell_edit) %>%
          mutate(diff = new_value - old_value)
      )
    })

    # return the data as a reactive
    return(data)
  })
}

mod_table_add <- function(id, data_aggreg) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # do the calculations
    data_table <- reactive({
      req(data_aggreg())
      data_aggreg() %>%
        summarise(
          Tot_old_value = sum(old_value) %>% round(), Tot_new_value = sum(new_value) %>% round(),
          Tot_diff = Tot_new_value - Tot_old_value %>% round(), Hausse_Tot = as.percent((Tot_new_value / Tot_old_value) - 1)
        )
    })

    # render the table
    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        data_table() %>% mutate(Hausse_Tot = format_value(f2, Hausse_Tot, " %")),
        rownames = FALSE, editable = "none"
      )
    })
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly ! I still have difficulties grasping differences between reactive, reactiveVal and reactiveValues as well as figuring when use which and how to tinker the observe functions, but this will greatly help me figure it out.

Comment: Yup. That was the same for me. Besides the differences in assigning and accessing values, reactiveVal and reactiveValues are basically the same. The first is used to store one value. The second for multiple values. And most of the time both are used when you want to assign or change a value inside an observe or observeEvent. I think Ch. 16 of mastering shiny has a lot of example when to use them and also a section on anti-patterns: https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-components.html#reactivity-components